# Unsatisfied link error in eclipse while programming J2ME Midlet

Tags: eclipse, java-me

Exception in thread "Main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.sun.midp.main.Configuration.getProperty0 (Ljava / lang / String;) Ljava / lang / String; 
    at com.sun.midp.main.Configuration.getProperty0 ( Native Method) 
    at com.sun.midp.main.Configuration.getProperty (Configuration.java: 32) 
    at com.sun.midp.lcdui.Resource.  (Resource.java: 30) 
    at com.sun.midp. main.Main.initSystemLabels (Main.java: 686) 
    at com.sun.midp.main.Main.main (Main.java: 103)

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `nativeSetTable()` is protected or private, that's why you don't see it. And moreover `nativeSetTable()` is a native method, which means that it is based on native code (already compiled for a specific processor and available in a specific lib [ie. a DLL]).

`UnsatisfiedLinkError` means that this particular method couldn't be retrieved and executed properly.

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate
>   native-language definition of a method declared native.

This means that your Java ME emulator must have missing `librairies`. You should try to reinstall it.

**Resources :**

- [Javadoc - UnsatisfiedLinkError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html)

Comment: You mean I must reinstall the Sun WTK ? These basically contain the devices right?